# 'value' is not a member of boost::mpl::aux::wrapped_type...when creating a mex function

Tags: c++11, boost, osx-elcapitan, mex

I am using an extensive piece of code which compiles in Windows and Linux with gcc>=4.7. It is a utility to seamlessly generate mex functions in Matlab from m-scripts written by someone. I am having trouble compiling a short c script (not provided here) in Mac os x. I am using gcc-4.8 with C++11. It uses Boost library only for headers. The piece of utility code where it gets stuck is:

```
/* gets mxClassID, given C type> 
    eg.   mx_class_id<float>()*/
template<typename T>
struct mx_class_id
{
    operator mxClassID()
    {
        return static_cast<mxClassID>(boost::mpl::at<mxInverseTypeMap,T>::type::value);
    }
};
```

required by

```
template<typename T>
mxArray* mxCreateScalar(const T & val)
{
    //mxClassID cid=static_cast<mxClassID>(boost::mpl::at<mxInverseTypeMap,T>::type::value);
    mxArray * arr=mxCreateNumericMatrix(1,1,mx_class_id<T>(),mxREAL);
    mxSetValue(arr,val);
    return arr;
}
```

What am I missing? Is it conflicting with built-in clang libraries? Or is it a header not specified (boost/mpl/at.hpp is included)? As I mention it does compile in Matlab for Windows and Linux.I have tried boost 1.51.0 (this is what we use) and also 1.56.0 (this is what Matlab uses) but I get the same error message.
The code I use to compile is

```
mex -v /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.8 -I path-to-boost-library -I path-to-private-library -I /usr/local/lib -std=C++11 script.cc
```

Here is the error message I am getting:

> error: 'value' is not a member of 'boost::mpl::aux::wrapped_type <
>   boost::mpl::aux::type_wrapper < mpl_::void_> >  ::type {aka
>   mpl_::void_}'

Any pointers or help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to answer with the information you have provided, but if I had to guess I'd say that the problem is that the type `T` is not contained in  the type sequence `mxInverseTypeMap`.

Comment: mx_class_id<T>::operator mxClassID() [with T = long unsigned int]'  and  mxCreateScalar(const T&) [with T = long unsigned int; mxArray = mxArray_tag]'. We use boost/cstdint.hpp

Comment: I'm not really sure, but [this](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxclassid.html#bqvsjjl-4) seems to be the translation table between C/C++ types and matlab. Is it possible that whatever type you are using is a typedef for `unsigned long long` in windows and linux and for `unsigned long` (which seems to be missing in that table) in mac? Can you try another compiler(clang for example)? Sorry for the wild guesses, I hope you solve the problem.

Comment: I figured that Matlab types have one to one correspondence with c types as defined in our function but size_t can be long unsigned or size_type. So the inverse function has an ambiguity and fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by the conflicting use of 'size_t' and 'unsigned long int'.
I think in Linux, Windows, size_t was employed in the code with the assumption it to be uint64_t. And it compiled in both.

However, for mac os x, it is either size_type or unsigned long int. This especially created problem because the code was matching c type to Matlab mex type with one-to-one mapping. In inverse mapping, with the use of size_t this one-to-one mapping was getting lost and instead became many-to-one. Once that was addressed it was easy to fix the rest.